# getnet returns Seller not enrolled

Tags: javascript

I want to pay with a debit card, but the API returns `"Seller not enrolled"`. I used a seller of test

i am sending this script tag:

```
import ScriptTag from "react-script-tag";

<ScriptTag
    async
    src="https://checkout-homologacao.getnet.com.br/loader.js"
    data-getnet-sellerid={payment.sellerId}
    data-getnet-token={payment.token}
    data-getnet-amount={formatMoney(maskAmount)}
    data-getnet-customerid={payment.customer.id}
    data-getnet-orderid={payment.orderId}
    data-getnet-button-class="open-checkout"
    data-getnet-customer-first-name={payment.customer.firstName}
    data-getnet-customer-last-name={payment.customer.lastName}
    data-getnet-customer-document-type={payment.customer.documentType}
    data-getnet-customer-document-number={removeSpecialChar(
      payment.customer.documentNumber
    )}
    data-getnet-customer-email={payment.customer.email}
    data-getnet-customer-phone-number={removeSpecialChar(
      payment.customer.phoneNumber
    )}
    data-getnet-customer-address-street={payment.address.street}
    data-getnet-customer-address-street-number={payment.address.number}
    data-getnet-customer-address-complementary={
      payment.address.complementary
    }
    data-getnet-customer-address-neighborhood={payment.address.neighborhood}
    data-getnet-customer-address-city={payment.address.city}
    data-getnet-customer-address-state={payment.address.state}
    data-getnet-customer-address-zipcode={removeSpecialChar(
      payment.address.zipcode
    )}
    data-getnet-customer-country={payment.address.country}
    data-getnet-items={payment.items}
    data-getnet-url-callback=""
    data-getnet-installments="4"
    data-getnet-gn3ds="false"
    data-getnet-gn3ds-currency="BRL"
    data-getnet-gn3ds-merchant-backend-url="https://api-homologacao.getnet.com.br/v2/hubbff/3ds/" //"https://api.com.br/v2/hubbff/3ds/"
    data-getnet-gn3ds-token-type="oauth"
    data-getnet-gn3ds-merchant-backend-token-oauth={`bearer ${token.access_token}`}
    data-getnet-gn3ds-environment="SDB" //PRD
    data-getnet-gn3ds-shipping-method="lowcost"
    data-getnet-gn3ds-framework-modal="bootstrap3"
    data-getnet-gn3ds-shipping-destination-code="01"
  />
```

Did anyone have this error before?
If anyone has any ideas - please help.

Answer (score 0):

brazilian developer here.

The "Seller not enrolled" error is when your client does not have the card brand (eg: Master, Visa, etc.) authorized to pay using debit.

You have to contact GetNet and ask them to enable the debit payment to your client.

Sorry about the bad english.

Best regards,
KingAlchemist